# Blazorise Chart Streaming

Tags: c#, charts, blazor, blazorise

I am using Blazorise library for chart streaming. I want to show in x axis not the realtime but only numbers from 0 to 1000. The chart should again contain the animation as it is so far.

Live-Chart looks this list: https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/chart-live

This chart streaming is based on chartjs-plugin-streaming: https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/latest/guide/

````
    <ChartStreaming @ref="@chartStreaming"
                    TItem="LiveDataPoint"
                    Options="new ChartStreamingOptions { Delay = 2000 }"
                    Refreshed="@OnHorizontalLineRefreshed" />
</LineChart>

    <Row>
    <Column>
        <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@(()=>chartStreaming.Pause())">Pause</Button>
        <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="@(()=>chartStreaming.Play())">Play</Button>
    </Column>
    </Row>

    @code{
    LineChart<LiveDataPoint> horizontalLineChart;
    ChartStreaming<LiveDataPoint>  chartStreaming;
    Random random = new Random( DateTime.Now.Millisecond );

    string[] Labels = { "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange" };
    List<string> backgroundColors = new List<string> { ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 99, 132, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 54, 162, 235, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 206, 86, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 75, 192, 192, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 153, 102, 255, 0.2f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 159, 64, 0.2f ) };
    List<string> borderColors = new List<string> { ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 99, 132, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 54, 162, 235, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 206, 86, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 75, 192, 192, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 153, 102, 255, 1f ), ChartColor.FromRgba( 255, 159, 64, 1f ) };

    public struct LiveDataPoint
    {
        public object X { get; set; }

        public object Y { get; set; }
    }

    object horizontalLineChartOptions = new
    {
        Scales = new
        {
            Y = new
            {
                Title = new
                {
                    Display = true,
                    Text = "Value"
                }
            }
        },
        Interaction = new
        {
            intersect = false
        }
    };

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync( bool firstRender )
    {
        if ( firstRender )
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(
                HandleRedraw( horizontalLineChart, GetLineChartDataset1 ) );
        }
    }

    async Task HandleRedraw<TDataSet, TItem, TOptions, TModel>( BaseChart<TDataSet, TItem, TOptions, TModel> chart, params Func<TDataSet>[] getDataSets )
        where TDataSet : ChartDataset<TItem>
        where TOptions : ChartOptions
        where TModel : ChartModel
    {
        await chart.Clear();

    await chart.AddLabelsDatasetsAndUpdate( Labels, getDataSets.Select( x => x.Invoke() ).ToArray() );
    }

    LineChartDataset<LiveDataPoint> GetLineChartDataset1()
    {
        return new LineChartDataset<LiveDataPoint>
        {
            Data = new List<LiveDataPoint>(),
            Label = "Dataset 1 (linear interpolation)",
            BackgroundColor = backgroundColors[0],
            BorderColor = borderColors[0],
            Fill = false,
            Tension = 0,
            BorderDash = new List<int> { 8, 4 },
        };
    }

    Task OnHorizontalLineRefreshed( ChartStreamingData<LiveDataPoint> data )
    {
        data.Value = new LiveDataPoint
        {
            X = DateTime.Now,
            Y = RandomScalingFactor(),
        };

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    double RandomScalingFactor()
    {
        return ( random.NextDouble() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : -1.0 ) * Math.Round( random.NextDouble() * 100      );
    }
}```
````

Comment: The question is unclear. If you only want to display 1000 values you don't need a streaming chart. Are you asking how to stream until you retrieve 1000 items then stop?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I want to stream for example from 0 to 1000 and then stop

Comment: Why not call `Pause` once you receive the 1000th item? What did you try? The code you posted here is a copy of the example, not your code